# Ruby on Rails has many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about my website. The scheme is as follows:

A user and a post has many comments.
Comments belongs to a user and a post.

I do

```
@specificpost = Post.first
```

then

```
@specificpost.comments
```

works perfectly fine.
But the problem is this:

```
@currentuser = User.first
```

works perfectly fine.

```
@currentuser.posts
```

give me the posts object,
but when I do

```
@currentuser.posts.comments
```

comments is unrecognized.

Succintly, I want to get all the comments that are written in the post of @currentuser

Thank you for reading this far! :)

Comment: you want the comments count for each post of the current user? @current_user.posts.map{|p| p.comments.count} that will return comments count for each post.

Comment: Orif you need the comments @current_user.posts.map{|p| p.comments} will get comments for each post in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `@currentuser.posts` gives me the posts object

NO. It gives a **collection** of `Post` objects. Each of them has their own comments, but the collection itself does not (it's a collection, after all, not a post).

> I want to get all the comments that are written in the post of @currentuser

*The* post? You have several. Which one do you want?

```
# comments of first post (if user has no posts, error will be raised. Also applies to other methods)
@current_user.posts.first.comments

# comments of last post
@current_user.posts.last.comments

# all comments of all posts
@current_user.posts.each_with_object([]) {|comments, memo| memo += comments}
```

Comment: When I say @current_user.posts.each_with .. etc, it gives an error that says undefined method `each_with_object' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This means that `@current_user.posts` is `nil`. Are you sure you have set up the relation correctly and this user does, in fact, have posts?